# Coroutine completely freezes Unity 2020.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I'm making a first-person game and am having trouble animating my character. I have the right animations in place. I need to find a way to make the game detect when the player has just landed on the ground so that I can play the 'landing' animation. The problem is that the only way I've thought of thus far to do this is with a coroutine. But the coroutine, when initiated, completely freezes my whole application. I suspect it's because the act of being midair initiates the coroutine once per frame. Here's the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAnimationHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
Animator animator;

IEnumerator LandDetect()  
{
    while (!playermove.isGrounded)
    {
        animator.SetBool("Midair", true);
    }
    animator.SetTrigger("Land");
    yield return null;
}

PlayerMove playermove;
void Start()
{
    // These are the two most important components for this 
    // script. I'll need PlayerMove for the mini-API
    // that I have in there and I'll need the animator
    // for obvious reasons.
    playermove = GetComponent<PlayerMove>();

    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    JumpHandler();
}

void JumpHandler()
{
    if (!playermove.isGrounded)
    {
        if (playermove.doubleJumpOccur)
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("DoubleJump");
            StartCoroutine(LandDetect());
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("Midair", true);
            StartCoroutine(LandDetect());
        }
    }
    else if (playermove.jumpOccur)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
        StartCoroutine(LandDetect());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the application doesn't leave

```
while (!playermove.isGrounded)
{
    animator.SetBool("Midair", true);
}
```

until you land. This loop is continuously executed in the same frame (which freezes your game) because you're not skipping frames. You need to put `yield return 0` (0, not null. Null won't cause the coroutine to skip any frames) somewhere in it so it can be resumed in the next frame. Also may remove `yield return null` at the end of the method, I doesn't do anything at this point

That's how I think it should look:

```
IEnumerator LandDetect()  
{
    while (!playermove.isGrounded)
    {
        animator.SetBool("Midair", true);
        yield return 0;
    }
    animator.SetTrigger("Land");
}
```

Also I don't know if using a coroutine is the best choice here. I usually use some trigger/collision detection for stuff like this.

Comment: That is correct except for the `yield return 0`. In a coroutine Unity doesn't care what exactly you `yield return` - if it is not a `YieldInstruction` or another `IEnumerator` than the value doesn't matter. `yield return null;` also yields for one frame. Actually it should be enough to call `animator.SetBool("Midair", true);` **once**, then wait until you land then set it to `animator.SetBool("Midair", false);` **once** ;)